# Bash variable truncated when passed into ffmpeg

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, read

I have an album of 11 `.flac` audio files. (**edit:** since this issue has been resolved, it's now clear that the precise names and content of the files are irrelevant, so I've renamed them):

```
> find . -name "*.flac"
./two.flac
./ten.flac
./nine.flac
./eight.flac
./seven.flac
./three.flac
./four.flac
./five.flac
./one.flac
./eleven.flac
./six.flac
```

I was converting these to `.wav` files with a specific sample rate and bit depth. I used `ffmpeg` in a Bash shell to do this. A command like this one works perfectly for each of the 11 files if I call it manually:

```
ffmpeg -i "./six.flac" -sample_fmt s16 -ar 44100 "./six.wav"
```

However, when I wrote a `while` loop to run this command for each file:

```
find . -name "*.flac" | sed "s/\.flac$//" | while read f; do ffmpeg -i "$f.flac" -sample_fmt s16 -ar 44100 "$f.wav"; done
```

This worked, but only for 8/11 of the files, with `ffmpeg` giving the following error messages for the three failures:

```
/ten.flac: No such file or directory
ree.flac: No such file or directory
ix.flac: No such file or directory
```

For `./ten.flac`, the leading `.` in the relative file path was truncated, resulting in an absolute path, and the other two, `./three.flac` and `./six.flac`, lose even more characters, including from the start of their basenames. Some of the other eight files had `./` truncated, but this resulted in the correct relative path, so `ffmpeg` was able to continue in these cases.

If I use the same loop structure, but with `echo "$f"` instead of calling `ffmpeg`, I see no problems with the output:

```
> find . -name "*.flac" | sed "s/\.flac$//" | while read f; do echo "$f"; done
./two
./ten
./nine
./seven
./three
./four
./five
./one
./eleven
./six
```

So I'm convinced the structure of the loop is fine, with `"$f"` expanding how I expect it to at each iteration. Somehow, when passing `"$f.flac"` into `ffmpeg`, part of the string is truncated, but only for some of the files.

**I just want to understand why my first attempt exhibited this behaviour. I'm not looking for an alternative way to loop over or convert the files (my second attempt, with a different kind of loop, was successful for all files).**

---

**edit:** I accidentally discovered that piping `yes |` into `ffmpeg` seems to fix this issue. I added this so I wouldn't be prompted to overwrite existing `.wav` files.

**edit:** Thanks @roaima for the explanation! Turns out that `ffmpeg` and `read` both inherit the same stdin handle, so `ffmpeg` could consume characters from the start of each line before `read` got a chance, thus mangling some of the file paths. This explains why `yes | ffmpeg ...` worked, since it gave `ffmpeg` a different stdin handle. The original loop works fine with `ffmpeg -nostdin ...`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089.

Comment: Strange the error shows  `9. Stranger.flac` when the file appears to be `09. Stranger.flac`.  Lots of things in bash/shell can strip leading 0s on numbers but I don't see anything you are doing that would, and it's inconsistent.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: I appreciate the links, gapsf, but as I said in the post, I just want to understand what is happening in this particular case; I'm not looking for another way to convert the files (I actually had them all converted hours ago).

Comment: sed "s/.flac//" -> sed "s/\.flac//"

Comment: You're right I should have escaped the dot in `sed`, but it makes no difference in this case, and certainly doesn't contribute to the substance of the question...

Comment: Check output of find . -name "*.flac" | sed "s/\.flac//"

Comment: The output of `find . -name "*.flac" | sed "s/\.flac//"` is identical to the loop with `echo "$f"` in the post.

Comment: Yes but you just edit and escape dot in regexp. Check your first variant find . -name "*.flac" | sed "s/.flac//"

Comment: I did check, and as I said, escaping the dot makes no difference in this case since none of the file paths contain "flac" anywhere other than in the extension. Exactly the same thing happens when I run the loop with the escaped dot in `sed`.

Comment: @jesse_b Setting `IFS=0` would do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a directory tree of files (not mentioned, and not shown in your example dataset), you can use a simple loop to process the files

```
for f in *.flac
do
    w="${f%.flac}.wav"
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -sample_fmt s16 -ar 44100 "$w"
done
```

If you really do have a hierarchy of files you can incorporate this into a `find` search

```
find -type f -name '*.flac" -exec sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do w="${f%.flac}.wav"; ffmpeg -i "$f" -sample_fmt s16 -ar 44100 "$w"; done' _ {} +
```

For efficiency you might want to skip processing of any `flac` that already has a corresponding `wav`. After the `w=` assignment, add `[ -s "$w" ] && continue`. If you really don't want that then you can further optimise the command thus,

```
find -type f -name '*.flac" -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$1" -sample_fmt s16 -ar 44100 "${1%.flac}.wav";' _ {} \;
```

For pre-run testing, prefix `ffmpeg` with `echo` to see what would get executed without it actually doing so. (Quotes won't be shown, though, so bear that in mind.)

---

It turns out that the question is actually about `ffmpeg` chewing up the filenames it's supposed to be processing. This is because `ffmpeg` reads commands from *stdin*, and the list of files has been presented as a pipe to a `while read …` loop (also using *stdin*).

Solution: `ffmpeg -nostdin …` or `ffmpeg … </dev/null`

See

- [Strange errors when using ffmpeg in a loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36411/100397)
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089

Comment: Why do we need loop with find at all? Simply exec ffmpeg without loop

Comment: @gapsf in the `find`? Partly I've used `find … +` to roll-up multiple flac files, and partly because I've written the code to more easily be modified to skip existing wav outputs

Comment: @roaima It's not to do with word splitting. I mentioned in another comment that even when I renamed all the files so they contained no spaces, the same thing occurred. Even when I name the files `one.flac` through to `eleven.flac`, I get the same issue, with error messages like `ree.flac: No such file or directory` (truncating the `th` in `three.flac`). I appreciate your alternative suggestions, but I wrote the question because I wanted to understand why the loop as I wrote it behaves as it does, and I'm no closer to understanding at the moment.

Comment: @Colm oh I see, I didn't realise that was the issue you wanted solving. `ffmpeg` reads from _stdin_, so you need to `ffmpeg … </dev/null` or `ffmpeg -nostdin …`. Answer updated

Comment: @roaima Thank you, `ffmpeg -nostdin ...` works! That also explains why `yes | ffmpeg ...` seemed to fix the issue, since `ffmpeg` takes stdin from the pipe.

Comment: "This is because ffmpeg reads commands from stdin" ... uhh, ok. But why does it read just a few characters here and there? :o

Comment: @ilkkachu https://stackoverflow.com/q/48635380/2344631